# Advice on Multithreading an emulator in C#. Pattern/Concepts

Tags: c#, multithreading, emulation

I'm working on a MIPS Emulator as a learning project. In order to get the desired performance I would like to have each processor always sleep in their own thread and when a DMA transfer occurs they start processing.

I've used the BackgroundWorker before and have just started using the async/away instructions and I've read about Thread Pooling. The "memory space" would be shared so the DMA status bits are the "natural" locking mechanism. These threading techniques don't seem to do what I would like. What am I missing?

Maybe this code example (Compiles, doesn't function) will explain what I'm thinking.

```
public class ThreadingEmulatorCode
{
    static Memory memory = new Memory();

    public ThreadingEmulatorCode()
    {
        CPU cpu = new CPU();
        memory.OnDMAZero += cpu.zero.Execute(new DMAEventArgs());
        memory.OnDMAOne += cpu.one.Execute(new DMAEventArgs());
        cpu.Run(ref memory);
    }
}

public delegate void dmazero(DMAEventArgs args);
public delegate void dmaone(DMAEventArgs args);

public class DMAEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public uint Address { get; set; }
}

public class Memory
{
    public event dmazero OnDMAZero;
    public event dmaone OnDMAOne;

    private const uint CoprocZeroDMA = 0x1FC00000;
    private const uint CoprocOneDMA = 0xBFC00000;
    private byte[] memory;

    public Memory()
    {
        this.memory = new byte[(8 * 1024 * 1024)];
    }

    public byte this[uint address]
    {
        get
        {
            return memory[address];
        }
        set
        {
            memory[address] = value;
            if (address == CoprocZeroDMA && OnDMAZero != null)
                OnDMAZero(new DMAEventArgs());
            if (address == CoprocOneDMA && OnDMAOne != null)
                OnDMAOne(new DMAEventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public class CPU
{
    public CoprocZero zero;
    public CoprocOne one;

    public void Run(ref Memory memory)
    {
         /* Start Executing Instructions */
    }

    public CPU()
    {
        zero = new CoprocZero();
        one = new CoprocOne();
    }
}

public class CoprocZero
{
    public CoprocZero(/* Start Listening Thread */) { }

    public dmazero Execute(DMAEventArgs dmaEvent)
    {
        /* Process DMA'd Data */
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CoprocOne
{
    public CoprocOne(/* Start Listening Thread */) { }

    public dmaone Execute(DMAEventArgs dmaEvent)
    {
        /* Process DMA'd Data */
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you are expecting versus what is actually happening?

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on how to give a sleeping thread a new workload.

Comment: First, you aren't performing any multi-threading in your example. Everything you have here would run in a single thread. For multi-threading, you will want to look into the `System.Threading` namespace.

Comment: This was a Q&D example to try and show what I want to do, I'll see if I can improve it a bit.

Comment: If you are worried about locking, there are several different techniques out there in .Net that handle it better than trying to handle your own locking. For example, take a look at [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) for examples of classes with built in thread-safe access. Even still, if you want to perform your own locking, A common way is to create a `private Object lockObj = new Object();` and simply `lock(lockObj) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: Thank you, I've read about concurrentqueues before but hadn't thought of them In a while, after you mentioned them the code came together pretty quick.

Comment: Sure. You can accept your own answer if you want to close this question. I can move my comment down to an answer if you would prefer that, but you figured out your own solution, I just threw a couple hints out there.

Comment: @gmiley I +1'ed your comment because it got me on the right path. I can't accept my own answer for 2 days. SO Rules. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to spend some more time with the code. Sorry. I originally expected that the tight while on TryPeek would max CPU, but it sits at Zero CPU in the Process List. I haven't verified total performance yet, but I think this will work.

```
// Code to Test
// ThreadingExampleCode stackOverflow = new ThreadingExampleCode();
// Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
public class ThreadingExampleCode
{
    public static Memory memory;
    private CoprocZero zero;
    private CoprocOne one;
    private CPU cpu;
    private Thread coprocZero;
    private Thread coprocOne;
    ConcurrentQueue<uint> coprocZeroQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<uint>();
    ConcurrentQueue<uint> coprocOneQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<uint>();

    public ThreadingExampleCode()
    {
        memory = new Memory();
        memory.OnDMAZero += MemoryOnOnDmaZero;
        memory.OnDMAOne += MemoryOnOnDmaOne;

        cpu = new CPU(memory);
        zero = new CoprocZero(memory, coprocZeroQueue);
        one = new CoprocOne(memory, coprocOneQueue);
        coprocZero = new Thread(zero.RunParm);
        coprocZero.Start();

        coprocOne = new Thread(one.RunParm);
        coprocOne.Start();

        cpu.Run();
    }

    private void MemoryOnOnDmaOne(DMAEventArgs args)
    {
        coprocOneQueue.Enqueue(args.Address);
    }

    private void MemoryOnOnDmaZero(DMAEventArgs args)
    {
        coprocZeroQueue.Enqueue(args.Address);
    }
}

public delegate void dmazero(DMAEventArgs args);

public delegate void dmaone(DMAEventArgs args);

public class DMAEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public uint Address { get; set; }
}

public class Memory
{
    public event dmazero OnDMAZero;
    public event dmaone OnDMAOne;

    public const uint CoprocZeroDMA = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    public const uint CoprocOneDMA = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    private byte[] memory;

    public Memory()
    {
        this.memory = new byte[(8 * 1024 * 1024)];
    }

    public byte this[uint address]
    {
        get { return memory[address]; }
        set
        {
            memory[address] = value;
            if (address == CoprocZeroDMA && OnDMAZero != null)
                OnDMAZero(new DMAEventArgs());
            if (address == CoprocOneDMA && OnDMAOne != null)
                OnDMAOne(new DMAEventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public class CPU
{
    private Memory memory;
    public CPU(Memory inMemory)
    {
        memory = inMemory;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        /* Start Executing Instructions */
        memory[Memory.CoprocZeroDMA] = 0x01;
        memory[Memory.CoprocOneDMA] = 0x01;
    }
}

public class CoprocZero
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<uint> queueToMonitor;
    private Memory memory;
    public CoprocZero(Memory inMemory, ConcurrentQueue<uint> queue)
    {
        memory = inMemory;
        queueToMonitor = queue;
    }

    public void RunParm()
    {
        uint memoryAddress;
        while (!queueToMonitor.TryPeek(out memoryAddress)) { };

        if (queueToMonitor.TryDequeue(out memoryAddress))
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}

public class CoprocOne
{
    private Memory memory;
    private ConcurrentQueue<uint> queueToMonitor;
    public CoprocOne(Memory inMemory, ConcurrentQueue<uint> queue)
    {
        memory = inMemory;
        queueToMonitor = queue;
    }

    public void RunParm()
    {
        uint memoryAddress;
        while (!queueToMonitor.TryPeek(out memoryAddress)) { };

        if (queueToMonitor.TryDequeue(out memoryAddress))
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```